# Azure VM Capture (Process Overview)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I am planning to capture my VM image in Azure to create a copy for VM deployments (I am using this to deploy multiple VM or any redeployment scenarios).

Will any data/ configurations lost during the process? Be it application wise or server. I am expecting it to work just as simple as copy and paste functionality no Gotchas. Everything within this VM is critical to my clients (Customized apps/ web services etc.)

P/S: I have done my research here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/

It says it will delete my VM once I have captured the image, now this is where I am very worried about.

Comment: I am assuming you are using ASM deployment.Take a look at [Exporting and Importing VM settings with the Azure Command-Line Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlining/2012/10/25/exporting-and-importing-vm-settings-with-the-azure-command-line-tools/). I suggest you to use **azcopy** to backup you OSDisk, and `azure vm show --json` to backup the detail configuration of your VM instance, and after you capture the vm image, use `azure vm create-from` to recreate your instance.

Answer (score 1):

Process of capturing the VM will preserve the installed applications, data and most settings. However, it does clear a few things like the computer name, network settings etc, so that the same image could be used to create multiple VMs later on.

Also, this process will delete your existing VM. You have to create a new VM using the image.

If you are unsure about any required settings that may be lost in this process, strong recommendation is to create a backup of the existing VM before you begin. You can do that by doing AzCopy of all the vhds on the VM (OS and Data disks). You could delete the backup after verifying the image deployments.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of creating Virtual Images:

1. **Without deprovisioning it**: Source VM is not destroyed. You should switch if off to avoid problems. If you create a VM from image their hostnames will clash. The idea is using this capture method for **backups**.
2. **After running waagennt -deprovision on it**: Source VM is destroyed in the process. You can create many VMs with no problem.**This is probably what you want to do**. Don't worry is harmless, apart of destroying source VM. You can always create a VM from that image. The idea is using this capture method for creating a base image and then have some kind of process to create and destroy servers (**Auto Scaling**).

   For example you create a web server for your app and instantiate more VMs in peak times.

**What does waagent exactly deprovision?**
**[waagent -deprovision](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/)** command clears some configuration on the machine. Exactly:

> This command will attempt to clean the system and make it suitable for
> re-provisioning. This operation performs the following tasks:
>
> - Removes SSH host keys (if Provisioning.RegenerateSshHostKeyPair is    'y' in the configuration file)
> - Clears nameserver configuration in    /etc/resolv.conf Removes the root user's password from /etc/shadow    (if
>   Provisioning.DeleteRootPassword is 'y' in the configuration file)
> - Removes cached DHCP client leases Resets host name to    localhost.localdomain
> - Deletes the last provisioned user account    (obtained from /var/lib/waagent) and associated data.

**Apart of this nothing will be touch on your server.**